# How to obtain the multinomial logistic regression via the framework of GLMs?

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression#As_a_set_of_independent_binary_regressions), the assumption we are making in multinomial logistic regression is that we take one class as "reference", say class $K$, and we assume that $\ln\left(\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=k_0)}{\mathbb{P}(X=K)}\right) = \beta_{k_0}^TX_i$. This very much feels like a GLM, though I do not know what is the distribution used in the GLM.

An educated guess would be the multinomial distribution, but then we have to specify $y$ as a vector, $y = (n_1, \dots, n_K)^T$, and I'm slightly worried here as I have not seen exponential parameterization of multivariate distributions, are they even a thing?

**EDIT:** On second thought $y$ is not a vector, rather just which class. Since the goal is multi-class classification, we don't use the general definition of multinomial distribution, but rather $\mathbb{P}(\text{Class}=k) = \binom{1}{1_{k=k_1}, \dots, 1_{k=k_K}}\prod_{i=1}^K p_1^{1_{k=k_1}}, \dots, p_K^{1_{k=k_K}}
$

Answer (score 1):

Multivariate generalized linear models are quite possible; see for example Fahrmeir and Tutz, "[Multivariate Statistical Modeling Based on Generalized Linear Models](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3454-6)," second edition, Springer, 2001. The multinomial distribution is appropriate for a multi-category outcome with no ordering among the levels. The link function is then a vector, representing the log-odds of each non-reference category against the reference category, based on a category-specific linear predictor.